# Why is my HTTPRequest being blocked by Cors when I provided the response headers?

Tags: post, cors, http-headers

I have a PHP script in my Cpanel filesystem that tries to insert a form into the database. This form contains some strings and 1 binary string that varies in size.

When I try to POST to this PHP script in my filesystem I get the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I've added the following headers, but it doesn't seem to be working. It happens in Chrome and Firefox but the POST works fine in Edge.

```
header("content-type: multipart/form-data");
header("access-control-allow-origin, *");
header("access-control-allow-credentials, true");
header("access-control-allow-methods, get,head,options,post,put");
header("access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-headers, origin,accept, x-requested-with, content-type, access-control-request-method, access-control-request-headers");
```

**Chrome Response**

[image]

**Edge Response**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the CORS headers are not included in the response.

It looks to me like your PHP syntax is wrong:

```
header('Content-type: multipart/form-data');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

Should surely be:

```
header('Content-type: multipart/form-data');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

Also not sure if the different capitalisation matters since HTTP/2 (that you are using) lowercases header names but you are returning mixed case.

Comment: I changed the correct systax and also tried lowercase but they did not show in the response.

Comment: Okay, well you were right after all I forgot to switch the , to : and it worked after that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good stuff. Please accept the answer then so others know the question has been resolved.